# Print the value chosen by GridSearchCV

Tags: python, classification, logistic-regression, grid-search

I want to choose the best values for `C` to obtain the best accuracy having this program. I know the parameter `C` can influence the results, so I used `GridSearchCV` to pick the right value for `C`. But how can I find out which value did he pick from that list?

```
param_grid  ={'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
    if (classifier == 'LogisticRegression'):
        build_classifier = globals()[classifier]()
        build_classifier = GridSearchCV(build_classifier, param_grid)
```

I tried with `print(build_classifier.best_estimator_)`, `build_classifier.best_params_` but I have some errors, so it's not the right print. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get errors because you didn't fit the model first. After fitting it, you can `print(build_classifier.best_estimator_)`